# Compare two dataframes cell by cell

Tags: r, dataframe, compare

Suppose we have two data frames as below

```
one <- data.frame("a" = c("aa", "bb"), "b" = c("cc", "dd"))

two <- data.frame("b" = c("aa", "bb"), "c" = c("ee", "ff"))
```

I was to compare each cell of data frame 'one' to each corresponding cell of data frame 'two' (without using for loops).  If the contents are identical I want to get a TRUE and if contents are not identical I want a `FALSE`.  The resulting `dataset` would look like

```
Col1    Col2

TRUE  FALSE

TRUE  FALSE
```

Is there any way to do this without using for loops?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Make sure your variables are characters and simply `one == two` will do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do

```
as.matrix(one) == as.matrix(two)
```

It is better to use `stringsAsFactors= FALSE` in the `data.frame` call to avoid the class of character elements getting converted to `factors`.  By converting to `matrix`, the class is now `character` and then use the cell by cell comparison with `==`

Comment: Great solution!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

G'day!.

You need to use `identical()`

```
one <- data.frame("a" = c("aa", "bb"), "b" = c("cc", "dd"))

two <- data.frame("b" = c("aa", "bb"), "c" = c("ee", "ff"))

three <- data.frame("a" = c("aa", "bb"), "b" = c("cc", "dd")) ## three is identical to one


identical(one, two) #returns FALSE

identical (one, three) #returns TRUE
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks but I need the True/False in each cell.  identical() compares the whole dataframe and not individual cells.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
result <- data.frame(Col1 = (as.character(one$a)==as.character(two$b)), 
                     Col2 = (as.character(one$b)==as.character(two$c)))
```

Output:

```
Col1  Col2
1 TRUE FALSE
2 TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks!  But the actual dataset I have had over 250 columns (sorry I did not mention that) and the code for this solution would become cumbersome.